# Элемент вызван не из того потока

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Делаю важный элемент в потоке. Запускаю поток из основного. И когда поток выполняется, студия ругается не на действие, а на условие(wtf????)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: студия ругается на действие - на чтение свойства Value. Используйте Invoke или async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишите небольшой вспомогательный класс:

```
public static class WinFormsSafeCallHelper
{
    public static T SafeGetValue<T>(this Control control, Func<T> func)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            return (T)control.Invoke(func);
        }

        return func();
    }
}
```

Теперь ваше условие можно переписать так:

```
if (trackBar1.SafeGetValue(() => trackBar1.Value >= 20))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Студия жалуется не на условие, а на обращение к элементу, созданного в другом потоке. Прочитайте про [Делегаты](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx). Можно убрать проверку на данную ошибку, но я вам не советую. Иногда такое получается...

Comment: Проблема в том, что я умею исправлять такие ошибки способом "if(control.InvokeRequired)". Но как исправить эту ошибку именно в теле if? Я был бы ужасно рад, если бы мне показали код, где в теле if используется Invoke.